# How to Set Size of Rendered Image

Tags: html2canvas

I'm confused with how to designate the size of the image that html2canvas generates. **For example, I'd like to be able to have my DIV remain 400px x 400px but have the rendered image be 1200px x 1200px.** I've looked at [the documentation](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration) but I'm misunderstanding how to apply it. I've tried adding `a.width: 1200; a.height: 1200;` without luck.

What am I doing wrong?

**My save function, from my JS:**

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  html2canvas($('#imagesave'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      a.download = 'myfile.png';
      a.click();
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="imagesave">
...
</div>

<button id="save">Save</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#imagesave {
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
html2canvas($('#imagesave')[0], {
  width: 1200,
  height: 1200
}).then(function(canvas) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  a.download = 'myfile.png';
  a.click();
});
```

You need to pass width and height as options to html2canvas as mentioned in [docs](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration). Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/7h0xf02x/) for the same.

```
html2canvas($('#imagesave')[0], {
  scale:3
}).then(function(canvas) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  a.download = 'myfile.png';
  a.click();
});
```

you can scale using scale attribute, which will scale horizontally and vertically with that much times.

Comment: This looks promising but how do I get the content of the div to scale with the new dimensions? In this example, shouldn't the red DIV be 1200 x 1200?

Comment: You want to scale the whole div?

Comment: I think I misunderstood something when I posted the question. You're on the right track, but yes; what I was trying to say was that I'd like the div to remain 400 x 400 (displayed to the user) but I'd like it scaled when generated as an image; this is mainly an attempt to get things clearer.

Comment: Marking this as solved as you answered what I asked! I will re-ask the question more correctly.

Comment: @codeforever if you want both with same multiplier you can use `scale`. check update

Comment: This is exactly what I was going for. Thank you.

Comment: even after I set my image to the correct width/height, I had to manually set the scale to 1, it seemed to default to 1.5 or something

Comment: this fix my issue, i need to include both width, height, and scale

Answer (score 2):

Just had a similar issue where I simply wanted the rendered image to be exactly the same size as my target div. The only thing that worked was to use [SeanMC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3705183/seanmc)'s and [Sruit A.Suk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812720/sruit-a-suk)'s suggestions of setting all 3 of the width, height AND scale.

```
html2canvas(myContainerDiv, {
    width: 1024,
    height: 1024,
    scale: 1
}).then(function (canvas) {
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    outputImage.src = data;
});
```